# How to verify that a BIND slave name server is actually synchronizing properly with master (and fix it afterwards)?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I've set up two name servers, a master and a slave according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-bind-dns-server-on-centos-6) link. The setup is functioning evidenced by the fact that sites featured on the master server gets served as expected.

Recently though, I've begun suspecting that the slave server doesn't synchronize correctly with the master. During an error inspection I tried reloading a random zone file:

```
rndc reload domain.tld
```

("domain.tld" being a placeholder)

only to be greeted by this:

```
zone refresh queued
```

Above is the message that is returned, regardless of domain tested.

I've tried searching the whole slave server for *any* zone files (find / -name *.zone), with no result (but since I'm not fully aware of how the BIND setup works, I'm not even sure that the slave server is supposed to contain the zone files like the master, making the search potentially redundant).

Then I checked the named.run log, it's filled with the likes of following entries:

```
dumping master file: tmp-CWKpRfrNi0: open: permission denied
```

Looks like a permission problem to me, but I'm honestly not entirely sure. BTW, I have also tried reloading zone files *after* incrementing the serial, with no luck.

1. Is there a way to verify that the slave server is functioning as intended?
2. Assuming above information is enough to conclude that en error is in fact the culprit and the server is faulty, how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried making a change to the zone and checking to see if it transfers to the slave?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to verify what information the slave contains...

Answer (score 1):

My bind-9.8.2-0.37 from CentOS 6 says after a slave is restarted (for each of the zones, even if they are already cached):

```
08-Apr-2016 12:15:07.571 zone example.com/IN: loaded serial 2016040103
```

The named.conf contains, among other stuff::

```
logging {
  channel general_file      { file "/var/log/named/general.log" versions 3 size 5m; severity dynamic; print-time yes; };
  category general      { general_file; };
};
```

No need to search for zone files, you should have them manually defined in named.conf, so their location should be easily determinable. Maybe you have chroot misconfigured, that is named runs thinking the root of the filesystem is somewhere like /var/named/chroot and it has no proper permissions set there.

Answer (score 0):

update serial for zone in master, rndc reload then grep serial in  /var/named/data/named.run at slave